# Current HTML page scrolls when opening in New Tab (No JS in Network), how to avoid the scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, vue.js

When I navigate using the "Ingredients" tab on the top mega menu, in the following link,

https://www.kerastase.com/care-for-your-hair/everything-you-need-to-know-about-fusio-scrub

the current page scrolls down, without any JS or HTML/CSS. What is the root cause of this jump?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by that `jump`? I found out that page is kinda `jumping` because the scrollbar is disappearing for a milisecond and this is caused by adding a `open` class to `body` element and then removing it while the page is still rendering.

Probably it is problem with Javascript in some kind of modal or maybe that fixed hamburger menu.

You can debug your website by clicking on `body` element then selecting `break-on` > `subtree-modifications` and then refresh your page. That's how I found out this bug.

Hope it helps, good luck with debugging! :)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed clear reply. But my query was for the "ingredients" tab. Where there isn't any pop up happening in the current page.It is mainly that the problem I am facing is after doing the click event. The current page scrolls down a bit. Only for the "ingredients" tab. Not sure how to identify it using inspect.